# ADF <globallyacceptedclaims>

Tags: configuration, ambient-data-framework

I'm wondering if it's possible to use wildcards within the cd_ambient_conf.xml  node (as documented [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US&docid=cd_ambient_confcd_ambient_confN10068&query=%2B%22globallyacceptedclaims%22))

This would save me a ton of data entry, and it would be cool if that's how it worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds from your question that you want to specify a wildcard in a Globally Accepted Claim and allow processing any forwarded claims that match this wildcard.

Unfortunately you cannot specify wildcards and need to specify each Globally Accepted Claim individually.

Here is how it works:
The ADF extracts the GloballyAcceptedClaims from the config and stores them in an list, where each claim is identified by its URI. When a claim comes in (i.e. is forwarded), the framework checks to see if the claim is contained within this list, e.g.:

```
if (this.globallyAcceptedClaims.contains(claimUri.toString()))
```

Your forwarded claim will have a specific URI, but an entry in the GloballyAcceptedClaims list will be a wildcard as per your desired config.  The String.contains() method will return false in this case, and the claim won't be processed.